# Powershell Remove members from DLs says not there, but they are

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, distribution-list

I have a powershell script that is supposed to empty a distribution list. It gets the member list into an array.  It then pipes the array into Remove-DistributionGroupMember.  Each run will have some members throw 'X isn't a member of the group Y' errors. At the end of the loop, I re-enumerate the users and for everyone that 'isn't a member of the group' error got thrown, is still a member of the group.  This is not consistent.  Sometimes everything works, but usually there are different members of the group that fail.

```
$grp = (Get-DistributionGroup -Identity:$DLIST -ErrorAction:Stop)
$members = (Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity:$grp -ErrorAction:Stop)
$members | % { 
    $member = $_
    try {
        Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity:$grp -Member:$_ -Confirm:$false -WarningAction:Stop -ErrorAction:Stop
        }
    catch {
        $LogStream.WriteLine((Get-Date).toString() + " Error removing ${member}:`n" + $_.toString())
        }
    }  
$members = (Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity:$grp -ErrorAction:Stop)
write-host "Users in List:"
$members | % { $LogStream.WriteLine("  " +  $_.ToString())}
```

> 3/20/2015 5:06:55 AM Error removing xxxxx.xxxx.com/North America/Spokane/Users/XXXXXX:
> The recipient "xxxx.xxxx.com/North America/Spokane/Users/XXXXX" isn't a member of the group "CN=*YYYYY,OU=IT,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=com".
>
> Users in List:
>
> xxxxx.xxxx.com/North America/Spokane/Users/XXXXXX

Comment: _is still a member of the group_ How are you verifying this? This sounds like it could be a replication issue between DC's. PowerShell is talking to one and you are looking at the other with AD for instance

Comment: In the same script, right after the deletes, I do another Get-DistributionGroupMember. For each member that returned 'is not a member' error, they appear in the list of group members.  Does each cmdlet make a new connection to AD?  If so, is there a way I can have the script connect once and stick with the DC?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the beginning of your script:

```
Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true
```

And I would also add the `-ResultSize "Unlimited"` to your `Get-` commands.